# Node.js API Server for querying a Neo4j database

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, express.js, neo4j

I've written a server in Node.js that listens to http requests via Express.js and forwards requests to a Neo4j server. It's my first time working with Neo4j and Express.js. The code runs as intended but is an eyesore to read.

The Database has the following Nodes and Relationships:

```
(:User)-[:RANTED]->(:Rant)
(:User)-[:UPVOTED]->(:Rant)
(:User)-[:DOWNVOTED]->(:Rant)
(:Rant)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(:Comment)
(:User)-[:COMMENTED]->(:Comment)
(:User)-[:UPVOTED]->(:Comment)
(:User)-[:DOWNVOTED]->(:Comment)
```

And the API simply supports creation of these nodes and relationships. Edit and Delete functionality is out of the project's scope.

**NOTE:** The server is meant for a simplistic social network for my final year university project. We are only being marked on the deliverables and not the code quality.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Design-Rant-Server",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Server layer between DR Database and Frontend",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "*",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "neo4j-driver": "*",
    "object-checker": "^0.3.24",
    "validator": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Paras DPain",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ParasDPain/DRServer.git"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
/** DR Starts server and API listeners
 *
 * Written By:
 *         Paras DPain
 *
 * License:
 *        MIT License. All code unless otherwise specified is
 *        Copyright (c) Paras DPain 2016.
 */
"use strict";

// REQUIRES
const express = require("express");
const bodyChecker = require('object-checker').bodyCheckMiddleware;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const validator = require('validator');
const db = require('./api.js');
const checkerOptions = require('./checkerOptions.js')

// GLOBALS
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// CONFIG
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// TODO validate auth here
// middleware to use for all requests - order of declaration is important
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request received');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});

/// ROUTES
// /api - test server status
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        message: "We are live!"
    })
});

// POST /api/user - create a user
router.route('/user')

// POST
.post(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.userOptions), function(req, res) {
    // TODO hash passwords
    db.CreateUser(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.pass, function(result) {
        if(result === true) { // API returns true if MERGE failed
            res.json({
                response: "User already exists"
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                response: "User successfully created!"
            });
        }
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});

// GET /api/user/:username - get user details
router.route('/user/:username')

// GET
.get(function(req, res) {
    // NULL check
    if (req.params.username.match(/^[a-z]+$/g) == null) {
        res.json({
            response: "Invalid Username"
        });
        return;
    }

    db.GetUser(req.params.username, function(result) {
        // Check if rant not found
        if (result && result.length > 0) {
            // result.get(key) filters out the required object
            res.json(result[0].get("user").properties);
        } else {
            res.json({
                response: "User not found"
            })
        }
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});

// GET /api/feed/:limit - get all rants
router.route('/feed/:limit')

// GET
.get(function(req, res) {
    // Limit type check
    var effectiveLimit;
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript
    // + converts string to int
    if (Number.isInteger(+req.params.limit) && +req.params.limit > 0) {
        effectiveLimit = +req.params.limit;
    } else {
        effectiveLimit = 10; // DEFAULT
    }

    db.GetRants(effectiveLimit, function(result) {
        // NULL rant check
        if(result.length > 0) {
            // filter and fill array with results
            var array = [];
            result.forEach(function(record) {
                array.push(record.get("rants").properties);
            });
            res.json(array);
        }
        else {
            res.json({"response" : "No Rants found"});
        }

    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});

// GET /api/rant/:rantId
router.route('/rant/:rantId')

// GET - get a rant
.get(function(req, res) {
    // Id format validation and string injection guard
    var id = req.params.rantId;
    // REGEX : start of string + 1 instance of char between [a-z] + integer of any length + end of string
    if (id.match(/^[a-z]\d+$/g) == null) {
        res.json({
            response: "Invalid Id"
        })
        return;
    }
    db.GetRant(id, function(result) {
        // Check if rant not found
        if (result.length > 0) {
            res.json(result[0].get("rant").properties);
        } else {
            res.json({
                response: "Rant not found"
            });
        }
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});

// POST-PUT-DELETE /api/rant
router.route('/rant')

// POST - create a rant
.post(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.rantCreateOptions), function(req, res) {

    // NULL checks
    if (req.body.username.length > 0) {
        res.json({
            response: "Username missing"
        })
        return;
    } else if (req.body.rantText.length > 0) {
        res.json({
            response: "Rant text missing"
        })
        return;
    }

    // Tags are optional
    var tags = req.body.tags;
    if (tags == null || tags.length < 1) {
        tags = [];
    }

    db.CreateRant(req.body.username, req.body.rantText, tags,
        function(result) {
            res.json({
                response: "Rant created successfully!"
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
})

// PUT - upvote the rant
.put(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.rantVoteOptions), function(req, res) {
    // TODO check username, rantId
    db.UpvoteRant(req.body.username, req.body.rantId,
        function(result) {
            res.json({
                response: "Rant upvoted successfully!"
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
})

// TODO use of DELETE request is misleading
// DELETE - downvote the rant
.delete(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.rantVoteOptions), function(req, res) {
    // TODO check username, rantId
    db.DownvoteRant(req.body.username, req.body.rantId,
        function(result) {
            res.json({
                response: "Rant downvoted successfully!"
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
});


// GET /api/rant/:rantId/comment
router.route('/rant/:rantId/comment')

// GET - get all comments for a rant
.get(function(req, res) {
    // Id format validation and string injection guard
    var id = req.params.rantId;
    // REGEX : start of string + 1 instance of char between [a-z] + integer of any length + end of string
    if (id.match(/^[a-z]\d+$/g) == null) {
        res.json({
            response: "Invalid Id"
        })
        return;
    }
    db.GetComments(id, function(result) {
        // filter and fill array with results
        var array = [];
        result.forEach(function(record) {
            array.push(record.get("comments").properties);
        });
        res.json(array);
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});

// POST-PUT-DELETE /api/rant/comment
router.route('/rant/comment')

// POST - Add a new comment
.post(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.commentCreateOptions), function(req, res) {
    // TODO check username, rantId, commentText
    db.CreateComment(req.body.username, req.body.rantId, req.body.commentText,
        function(result) {
            res.json({
                response: "Comment added successfully!"
            });
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
})

// PUT - upvote the comment
.put(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.commentVoteOptions), function(req, res) {
    db.UpvoteComment(req.body.username, req.body.commentId,
        function(result) {
            res.send("Comment upvoted successfully!");
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
})

// DELETE - downvote the comment
.delete(bodyChecker(checkerOptions.commentVoteOptions), function(req, res) {
    db.DownvoteRant(req.body.username, req.body.commentId,
        function(result) {
            res.send("Comment downvoted successfully!");
        },
        function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        });
});

// REGISTER ROUTES
app.use("/api", router);

// MAIN
app.listen(port);
console.log("The server has started");
```

**dbconnector.js**

```
/** Neo4j database connector
 *
 * Written By:
 *         Paras DPain
 *
 * License:
 *        MIT License. All code unless otherwise specified is
 *        Copyright (c) Paras DPain 2016.
 */
"use strict";

// REQUIRES
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver").v1;
const db_auth = require("./config.json");

// GLOBALS
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic(db_auth.username, db_auth.pass));

// Method perform all queries to the database
exports.query = function(query, params, result, callback) {
    var session = driver.session();
    var collection = []; // Keep a record of all results
    session
        .run(query, params)
        .subscribe({
            onNext: function(record) {
                collection.push(record);
            },
            onCompleted: function() {
                if (result) {
                    result(collection);
                }
                session.close();
            },
            onError: function(err) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(err);
                }
            }
        });
};
```

**api.js**

```
/** Contains implements of all API methods
 *
 * Written By:
 *         Paras DPain
 *
 * License:
 *        MIT License. All code unless otherwise specified is
 *        Copyright (c) Paras DPain 2016.
 */
"use strict";

// TODO scores missing from rants

// REQUIRES
const async = require('async');
const queryDB = require('./dbconnector.js').query;

// HELPER METHODS
// Method checks relationships between two nodes and performs operations selectively
var performVotes = function(primaryNode, secondaryNode, pValue, sValue, novote, callback) {
    var relationshipType;
    // fetch existing relationship between the nodes
    async.series([
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (primary : " + primaryNode[0] + " {" + primaryNode[1] + " : {pKey} })" +
                "-[relationship]->" +
                "(secondary : " + secondaryNode[0] + " {" + secondaryNode[1] + " : {sKey} }) " +
                "RETURN type(relationship) AS relationship",
                {
                    pKey: pValue,
                    sKey: sValue
                },
                function(result) {
                    if(result.length > 0) {
                        relationshipType = result[0].get("relationship") + "";
                    } else {
                        relationshipType = "";
                    }
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                function(err) {
                    callback(err);
                    return; // stop further processing
                }
            );
        },
        // Redundant wrap required for async
        function switchByResult() {
            switch (relationshipType) {
                case "COMMENTED": // Operation not allowed
                    callback("Cannot vote your own comments");
                    break;
                case "RANTED": // Operation not allowed
                    callback("Cannot vote your own rants");
                    break;
                case "UPVOTED": // already upvoted
                    callback("Node is already upvoted");
                    break;
                case "DOWNVOTED": // already downvoted
                    callback("Node is already downvoted");
                    break;
                case "": // No relationship found
                    if (novote) {
                        novote();
                    };
                    break;
                default: // Unknown relationship found
                    callback("Unknown relationship status found");
                    cb(null, "");
            };
        }
    ]);
};

// GLOBALS
var rantCount = 0;
// Fetch current rant count
queryDB("MATCH (r : Rant) RETURN count(*) AS count", {}, function(result) {
    rantCount = result[0].get("count").toString();
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
});
// async.series helper method
var cb = function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
}

// API Implements
exports.GetUser = function(username, result, callback) {
    var foundUser;
    var score;

    // Find scores ((upvoted rants - downvoted rants) + (upvoted comments - downvoted comments))
    // TODO simplify into a single CYPHER query
    async.series([
        // Upvoted rants
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (user)-[:RANTED]->(rants : Rant) " +
                "MATCH (:User)-[uprants : UPVOTED]->(rants) " +
                "RETURN COUNT(uprants) AS count", {
                    uname: username
                },
                function(countRes) {
                    score = countRes[0].get("count").toNumber();
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        },

        // Downvoted rants
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (user)-[:RANTED]->(rants : Rant) " +
                "MATCH (:User)-[downrants : DOWNVOTED]->(rants) " +
                "RETURN COUNT(downrants) AS count", {
                    uname: username
                },
                function(countRes) {
                    score -= countRes[0].get("count").toNumber();
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        },

        // Upvoted comments
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (user)-[:COMMENTED]->(coms : Comment) " +
                "MATCH (:User)-[upcoms : UPVOTED]->(coms) " +
                "RETURN COUNT(upcoms) AS count", {
                    uname: username
                },
                function(countRes) {
                    score += countRes[0].get("count").toNumber();
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        },

        // Downvoted comments
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (user)-[:COMMENTED]->(coms : Comment) " +
                "MATCH (:User)-[downcoms : DOWNVOTED]->(coms) " +
                "RETURN COUNT(downcoms) AS count", {
                    uname: username
                },
                function(countRes) {
                    score -= countRes[0].get("count").toNumber();
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        },

        // Get User and add calculated scoee
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB("MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} }) RETURN user", {
                    uname: username
                },
                function(finalRes) {
                    if (finalRes.length > 0) { // NULL CHECK
                        finalRes[0].get("user").properties["score"] = score;
                    }
                    result(finalRes); // return
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        }
    ]);
};

exports.CreateUser = function(username, email, passHash, result, callback) {
    queryDB(
        "MERGE (user : User {username : {uname}, email : {uemail}, hash : {uhash} }) " +
        "ON MERGE RETURN TRUE", // return true if user already exists
        {
            uname: username,
            uemail: email,
            uhash: passHash
        },
        result,
        callback);
};

exports.GetRants = function(resultLimit, result, callback) {
    var rantArray;
    async.series([
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB("MATCH (rants : Rant) RETURN rants LIMIT {limit}", {
                limit: resultLimit
            },
            function(res) {
                rantArray = res;
                cb(null, "");
            },
            callback);
        },

        // Foreach rant, add it's score
        // TODO multiple calls should be fixed by refactoring the database design
        function fn(cb) {
            var callCount = 0; // HACK to enforce all function calls to return
            async.eachOf(rantArray, function(element, index , cbb) {
                queryDB(
                    "OPTIONAL MATCH (user : User)-[:UPVOTED]->(:Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                    "WITH COUNT(user) AS upvotes " +
                    "OPTIONAL MATCH (user : User)-[:DOWNVOTED]-(:Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                    "RETURN upvotes - COUNT(user) AS count", {
                        rid: element.get("rants").properties.id
                    },
                    function(res) {
                        element.get("rants").properties["score"] = res[0].get("count").toNumber();
                        console.log(res[0].get("count").toNumber());

                        callCount++;
                        // HACK callback
                        if(callCount === rantArray.length) {
                            console.log("we here with array as");
                            result(rantArray);
                            cb(null, "");
                        }
                    },
                    callback);
            }, function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
};

exports.GetRant = function(rantId, result, callback) {
    var score;
    async.series([
        // User Votes
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB(
                "OPTIONAL MATCH (user : User)-[:UPVOTED]->(:Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                "WITH COUNT(user) AS upvotes " +
                "OPTIONAL MATCH (user : User)-[:DOWNVOTED]-(:Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                "RETURN upvotes - COUNT(user) AS count", {
                    rid: rantId
                },
                function(countRes) {
                    score = countRes[0].get("count").toNumber();
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        },

        // Get Rant details
        function fn(cb) {
            queryDB("MATCH (rant : Rant {id : {rid} }) RETURN rant", {
                    rid: rantId
                },
                function(finalRes) {
                    if (finalRes.length > 0) { // NULL CHECK
                        finalRes[0].get("rant").properties["score"] = score;
                    }
                    result(finalRes); // return
                    cb(null, "");
                },
                callback);
        }
    ]);
};

exports.CreateRant = function(username, rantText, tags, result, callback) {
    queryDB(
        "MATCH (user : User {username: {uname} }) " +
        "CREATE (rant : Rant {id : {rid}, text : {rText}, tags : {rTags} })" +
        "CREATE (user)-[:RANTED {on: {time} }]->(rant)", {
            uname: username,
            rid: "r" + ++rantCount,
            rText: rantText,
            rTags: tags,
            time: Date.now()
        },
        result,
        callback);
};

exports.GetComments = function(rantId, result, callback) {
    queryDB(
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (rant : Rant {id : {rid} })" +
        "-[:HAS_COMMENT]->" +
        "(comments : Comment) RETURN comments", {
            rid: rantId
        },
        result,
        callback);
};

exports.CreateComment = function(username, rantId, commentText, result, callback) {
    // Fetch comment count
    var commentCount = 0;
    queryDB(
        "OPTIONAL MATCH (r : Rant {id : {rid} })" +
        "-[c : HAS_COMMENT]->" +
        "(:Comment) RETURN count(c) AS count", {
            rid: rantId
        },
        function(res) {
            commentCount = res[0].get("count").toString(); // fetch current rant count

            // Inject main function
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username: {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (rant : Rant {id : {rid} })" +
                "CREATE (com : Comment {id : {cid}, text : {cText} })" +
                "CREATE (rant)-[:HAS_COMMENT {on: {time} }]->(com)" +
                "CREATE (user)-[:COMMENTED]->(com)", {
                    uname: username,
                    rid: rantId,
                    cid: "c" + ++commentCount,
                    cText: commentText,
                    time: Date.now()
                },
                result,
                callback);

        },
        function(err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        });
};

/*
 * Voting API functions lineraly and leaves UX features of toggling votes to the frontend
 */
 // TODO Implement checks for non matches to protect against wrong input
exports.UpvoteRant = function(username, rantId, result, callback) {
    performVotes(["User", "username"], ["Rant", "id"], username, rantId,
        function() {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username: {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (rant : Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                "CREATE (user)-[:UPVOTED]->(rant) ", {
                    uname: username,
                    rid: rantId
                },
                function(res) {
                    result("Rant upvoted successfully!")
                },
                callback);
        },
        callback);
};

exports.DownvoteRant = function(username, rantId, result, callback) {
    performVotes(["User", "username"], ["Rant", "id"], username, rantId,
        function() {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} })" +
                "-[relationship : DOWNVOTED]->" +
                "MATCH (rant : Rant {id : {rid} }) " +
                "DELETE relationship", {
                    uname: username,
                    rid: rantId
                },
                function(res) {
                    result("Rant downvoted successfully!")
                },
                callback);
        },
        callback);
};

exports.UpvoteComment = function(username, commentId, result, callback) {
    performVotes(["User", "username"], ["Comment", "id"], username, commentId,
        function() {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username: {uname} }) " +
                "MATCH (com : Comment {id : {cid} }) " +
                "CREATE (user)-[:UPVOTED]->(com)", {
                    uname: username,
                    cid: commentId
                },
                function(res) {
                    result("Comment upvoted successfully!")
                },
                callback);
        },
        callback);
};

exports.DownvoteComment = function(username, commentId, result, callback) {
    performVotes(["User", "username"], ["Comment", "id"], username, commentId,
        function() {
            queryDB(
                "MATCH (user : User {username : {uname} })" +
                "-[relationship : DOWNVOTED]->" +
                "MATCH (com : Comment {id : {cid} })" +
                "DELETE relationship", {
                    uname: username,
                    cid: commentId
                },
                function(res) {
                    result("Comment downvoted successfully!")
                },
                callback);
        },
        callback);
};
```

**checkerOptions.js**

```
/** Validation options for object-checker to validate incoming requests
 *
 * Written By:
 *         Paras DPain
 *
 * License:
 *        MIT License. All code unless otherwise specified is
 *        Copyright (c) Paras DPain 2016.
 */
"use strict";

// REQUIRES
const validator = require('validator');

// CHECKER OPTIONS
exports.userCreateOptions = {
    username: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]+$/
    },
    email: {
        $assertTrue: validator.isEmail
    },
    pass: {
        // TODO
    }
};
exports.rantCreateOptions = {
    username: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]+$/g
    },
    rantText: {
        $minLength: 1
    },
    tags: {
        $isOptional: true,
        $isArray: true
    }
};
exports.rantVoteOptions = {
    username: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]+$/g
    },
    rantId: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]\d+$/g
    }
}
exports.commentCreateOptions = {
    username: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]+$/g
    },
    rantId: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]\d+$/g
    },
    commentText: {
        $minLength: 1
    }
};
exports.commentVoteOptions = {
    username: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]+$/g
    },
    commentId: {
        $matchRegExp: /^[a-z]\d+$/g
    }
};
```

One noticeable improvement might be `exports.GetUser` inside `dbconnector.js`. The method makes five different calls to the database to calculate the User's `score`.

I did try to implement it in a single `neo4j` query but due to issues with the behaviour of the `OPTIONAL MATCH` function (documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817318/cypher-different-counts-return-the-same-result), no the solution didn't work for more than two `MATCH`s) I decided separate the query. If there is a better solution, do let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often a good idea to **separate routes** into their own files to get a better overview of the project. Try out [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) and see how the example project is organized.

Use a **logging framework** to log requests. I've used [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) which is really nice.

**Callbacks** are like any other parameters and should be given a descriptive name. For instance, `query` has two callback parameters, `result` and `callback`. A more descriptive name would perhaps be `resultCallback` and `errorCallback`. `performVotes` even has both `callback` and `cb`, which is very confusing to a reader!

**Comments** is a very useful tool to help readers understand particularly tricky code. They can however lead to less readable code when used too much. Obvious comments like `// REQUIRES` before a block of `require` calls are simply a nuance in my opinion.

I don't know if I'm missing something, but it seems like your **routing comments** are misleading. They all mention the prefix `/api`, but I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Assignment is not necessary when **defining functions**. You can drop `var` and `=` in the definition of `performVotes`.

In fact, **don't use `var`** at all. Since ES6, the new version of JavaScript, there are two new assignment statements `const` and `let`. `let` roughly corresponds to `var`, but with saner rules, while `const` is a whole new concept that should be used whenever reassignment isn't strictly required. Read [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75#.qw5umcdoq) if you're interested in why.

> Sometimes it’s tempting to create an identifier to represent some data
>   and then use that identifier as a temporary place to store values in
>   transition from one representation to another.
>
> For instance, you may be after a query string parameter value, and
>   start by storing an entire URL, then just the query string, then the
>   value. This practice should be avoided.
>
> It’s easier to understand if you use one identifier for the URL, a
>   different one for the query string, and finally, an identifier to
>   store the parameter value you were after.
>
> This is why I favor `const` over `let` in ES6. In JavaScript, `const`
>   means that the identifier can’t be reassigned.
>
> [...]
>
> `var` is now the weakest signal available when you define a variable
>   in JavaScript. The variable may or may not be reassigned, and the
>   variable may or may not be used for an entire function, or just for
>   the purpose of a block or loop.

Generally you should avoid **global mutable state**. `rantCount` can easily lead to race conditions and other hard to track bugs. I don't know Neo4j, but databases usually have some atomic increment feature to do globally unique ids you could use instead.

checkerOptions.js has lots of **duplicated code**. Say you want to make a change to allow usernames with upper case letters and numbers as well. You'll have to edit five different regexes! Instead, define a globals for username and id patterns and reuse them.

```
const USER_NAME_PATTERN = /^[a-z]+$/g;
```

Concerning these **regular expressions**, there's no need for the `g` flag in your case. It stores the index of each match to allow multiple matches on the same string, but since all your patterns are anchored with `^` and `$`, only one match is ever possible!